# Определить версию пакета Bouncycastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Возникла необходимость в компиляции одной старой библиотеки, которая использует классы из `Bouncycastle`.

Во время сборки компилятор ругается на:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509AttributeCertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.BEROutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream;
```

Насколько я понимаю, я использую новую версию `Bouncycastle`, в которой эти классы уже убрали.

Подскажите какую версию Bouncycastle нужно найти(старые версии), в которых эти классы объявлены?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Классы `BEROutputStream`, `DEROutputStream` находятся в файле `bcprov-xxx.jar` и согласно документации были помечены как устаревшие (deprecated) в [версии 1.63](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.63/deprecated-list.html):

> `org.bouncycastle.asn1.BEROutputStream(OutputStream)`
> Will be removed from public API.
> Use `ASN1OutputStream.create(OutputStream, String)` with `ASN1Encoding.BER` instead.

> `org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream`
> Will be removed from public API.

Начиная с версии 1.67, эти классы были удалены.

---

Класс `X509CertificateHolder` находится в jar-файле `bcpkix-xxx.jar` НЕ является устаревшим и доступен, начиная как минимум с версии 1.47 до последних версий 1.70+ в зависимости от версии JDK (см. [документацию](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk18on/latest/index.html)).

- [jdk15to18 - 1.63](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15to18/1.63/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509AttributeCertificateHolder.html)
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- [jdk15to18 - 1.75](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15to18/latest/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509AttributeCertificateHolder.html)
- [jdk15on - 1.47](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.47/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509AttributeCertificateHolder.html) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- [jdk15on - 1.70](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.70/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509AttributeCertificateHolder.html) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- [jdk18on - 1.71](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk18on/1.71/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509AttributeCertificateHolder.html)
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавил в проект следующие библиотеки:

`-bckix-jdk15on-1.57.jar`
`-bcprov-jdk15on-1.57.jar`
`-bctls-jdk15on-1.57.jar`

Практически ушли все ошибки.
Но остались

`import org.bouncycastle.asn1.BEROutputStream;`
`import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream;`

Comment: Хм, через мавен подключали?

Comment: Нет. Нет опыта. И машина на которой собираю проект не подключена к инету.